# How do I update value of an array inside ref in vue 3

Tags: arrays, vue.js, ref

I am building an application with vuejs

I have a ref which contains an array and I want to update a single value inside it

```
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
      const allQuestions = ref([{"like" => 1},{"like" => 0}]);
      allQuestions.value[1].like = 1;
   }
}
```

I want to update the second like in the ref array.

Comment: why are you using `=>`? isn't that showing you an error?

Answer (score 5):

Javascript uses a different syntax than php for objects.

```js
const allQuestions = ref([{like:1},{like:0}]);
allQuestions.value[1].like = 1
```